# Jquery- Unable to get alert after changeing the select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get alert on change of select box option.

Here, i added a css class name on each selectbox while iterating it in the loop, and finally i called the jquery function with class selector.

But i do not know why its not showing alert on change of selectbox dropdown. Please help me to solve this problem

```
  <table style="border:1px solid red;" width="650px">
<tr style="border:1px solid red;">
<td">Status</td>
</tr>
<?php
$qry = "select *from tracker group by orderno";
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($data =  mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<tr style="border:1px solid red;">
<td  ><label onclick="show(this.id)" id=<?php echo $data['orderno'];?> > <?php echo $data[1]; ?></label></font></td>
<td  ><?php echo  $data['customername'];  ?></td>
<td align="center" style="border:1px solid red;"><?php  echo $data['noofbooks']; ?></td>
<td  ><?php echo $data['address']; ?></td>
<td  ><?php echo $data['mobileno'];  ?></td>
<td align="center" style="border:1px solid red;">

    <select name="status" class="selectboxid">  
<?php 
if($data['status']  == "despatch")
{
        echo '<option name="despatched" selected="selected" value="despatched"> Despatched </option>';
}
else
    {
    echo '<option name="despatched"   value="despatched"> Despatched </option>';
}
  if($data['status'] == "Pending")
{
        echo '<option name="pending" selected="selected" value="pending"> pending </option>';
}
else{
   echo '<option name="pending"  value="pending"> pending </option>'; 
}
  if($data['status'] == "deliver")
{
        echo '<option name="despatched" selected="selected" value="despatched"> Despatched </option>';
}
else
    {
    echo '<option name="despatched" value="despatched"> Despatched </option>';
}
  if($data['status'] == "partial")
{
        echo '<option name="partial" selected="selected" value="partial"> Partial </option>';
}
else
{
    echo '<option name="partial" value="partial"> Partial </option>';
}
 ?>

</select>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

And my jquery code is;

```
<script>
$(".selectboxid").change(function() { 
    alert("hi");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your use of jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` function? Oftentimes this will execute before the element exists and will not bind to anything. And since you're asking about a jQuery issue (front end) you shouldn't include your PHP code but just a select box and the Javascript that isn't working as expected. Also ideally, use something like jsFiddle to demo the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you are including jQuery library?

Comment: @izuriel it works after including it inside `$(function() {
//...
});`  .Actually i forget this. So now my problem is solved, so shall i delete this question now?, i do think this question required any answer now, & no use for others also.

Comment: @user1671639   it works after including it inside $(function() { //... }); .Actually i forget this. So now my problem is solved

Comment: You can accept any answer provided that would provide a clear and accurate answer or answer it yourself explaining how you solved it. There is no reason to delete the question.

Comment: @izuriel 1 person below answer, shall i accept it?

Comment: just saw what you guy talking. Man I feel bad, LOL.

Comment: @Chokchai Why you feel bad? Your answer is also good. I will accept it after when stack-overflow allow me after few mins.

Comment: Because I'm the one who answer you below. you get it ?

Comment: @Chokchai Don't feel bad, I posted a comment instead of an answer and you provided an accurate answer to resolve the posted question. Nothing to feel bad about!

Comment: @Chokchai Its not like that, before then you already Mr Isurial answer my question in this comment. & after implementing his comment i got my output correctly. Then after wards you have answer. Anyway i accepted your answer, you have added more useful info.

Comment: Yeah I understand that why I said LOL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you bind event too soon (before DOM is loaded). Just put jQuery function in `jQuery(function(){  })` like code below.

for optional you should use `on` instead of `change`, its a recommend style.

```
jQuery(function(){
   $(".selectboxid").on('change', function() { 
       alert("hi");
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use this, dont need $(document).ready...

```
<script>
$(document).on("change",".selectboxid",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
</script>
```